# Linux (Mint) eats all my RAM

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, ram, memory-leaks

I know, there are plenty of "Linux eat my RAM" threads all over the internet, but they can't help me to solve my problem.
(I had a try with this question on askubuntu but I'm off-chart with Mint)

At home my workstation is a Mint19/Ubuntu18.04/Cinnamon box, used for Java/BigData development.

Some time, not every day, after some hours of work, my Intellij IDE becomes laggy, due to missing RAM.

If I look the "top", I see that only some Mo of the 16G RAM are available and that system is swapping.

I can't understand where the +10G RAM are used for. Some time ago, this happened. To have a better understanding, I CTRL-F1 to a non graphical sessions, then I stopped the LightDM X-Server.

So all the RAM eating graphical apps (skype, slack, chrome etc...) are off. And only the system daemons are alive. After this purge "free" gives me :

```
Mem:       16130044    11507836     3615496         704     1006712     4287260
Swap:    15625212      541820    15083392
```

So, the XServer stop made me recover ~4G, but 11G are always missing /proc/meminfo looks like :

```
MemTotal:       16130044 kB
MemFree:         3613360 kB
MemAvailable:    4285680 kB
Buffers:          109512 kB
Cached:           744668 kB
SwapCached:        31984 kB
Active:           433228 kB
Inactive:         492328 kB
Active(anon):      39192 kB
Inactive(anon):    32920 kB
Active(file):     394036 kB
Inactive(file):   459408 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:      15625212 kB
SwapFree:       15083392 kB
Dirty:               220 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         66456 kB
Mapped:            75056 kB
Shmem:               704 kB
Slab:             583976 kB
SReclaimable:     153108 kB
SUnreclaim:       430868 kB
KernelStack:        8624 kB
PageTables:        16852 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    23690232 kB
Committed_AS:    3990300 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     8152580 kB
DirectMap2M:     8331264 kB
DirectMap1G:     1048576 kB
```

Missing RAM is not in SLAB (there are some threads about that)

I tried several things :

- various versions of sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
- kernel upgrade (actually on 4.15.0-173)
- Rootkit analysis...

But nothing helped

Any idea ?

Comment: so, when you malloc 10 GB and write random data to each page (i.e., writing a byte every 4KB suffices, no need to write all 10 GB), does it really start to swap?

Comment: if you disable starting X at all and reboot, does the `free` look the same?

Comment: After a level 3 fresh boot, `free` looks perfect : `Mem:       16130044      730932    14219848        2248     1179264    15100864 Swap:    15625212           0    15625212`

Comment: Marcus, after a fresh reboot, I tried to fill (and exceed) RAM with this command : `cat /dev/zero | head -c 20G | tail`. Swapping happened : `Mem:       16130044    15772488      188188        1536      169368       98668 Swap: 15625212     8957696     6667516`

Comment: It seems that the Nvidia driver is the culprit. I found that by successive tests (I know that graphics drivers are often the cause of weird problems). I wonder how I could have objectify this analysis (analyze the use of RAM to bring me to the NVIdia driver)

Comment: deep dive you'Re setting yourself up for! You can use ebpf to trace who and when `kmalloc`, `kmem_cache` or `vmmaloc` are called in the kernel.